# Archiso install does not load after passing GRUB

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation

I created a custom iso file following [The official documentations](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Archiso). I coppied the iso file onto a USB and tried to boot into both a virtual machine and empty machine. I got the Arch Linux splash screen but when I try to boot it, the counter at the bottom simply resets. and nothing else happens

I made sure to enable the login manager (lxde) at startup.

I am new to Arch but not to linux. Please let me know what other information i can share to help. Thank you